# UIBarButtonItem font weight changes after push pop of navigation stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem, "Done" - created in storyboard IB for ViewController A.

ViewController A is the root View Controller of the navigation stack.

If I push a View Controller B onto the navigation stack and then pop it again. the font weight of the Done button changes.

[image: Start Scenario - A]
[image: B pushed onto stack]
[image: B popped from the stack]

The font colour of the Done button is applied in A.viewWillAppear(..) and looks pretty much like

```
doneButton.tintColor = [CMPThemes navigationBarItemColour]; // it's a blue
```

- I have stripped all appearance proxy code from the app (because there
  are more than one style of navigation bars/buttons/titles appear in
  the app) so I'm not looking for a fix that can only be done via the
  appearance proxy...
- I have checked in the debug view hierarchy that the Done button is
  the same instance before and after the transitions
- I have tried to re-apply the tint colour after the pop
- I don't apply a font weight anywhere in the process
- Also, to my eye, the font and font size seem to be unchanged during
  the process.

In ViewController A

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
    ...
```

In ViewController B

```
viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrowLeft"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
    backButton.tintColor = CMPThemes.popoverNavigationBarItemColour()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = backButton
}
```

The storyboard looks like: (I've added the A and B to the image to maintain clarity).

[image]

If someone recognises the problem and can point me in the right direction for a fix that would be great!

Comment: Seem like in viewController B you have some custom UI such as back button. Maybe when creating custom back button, you did something affect done button. It's easier what is the problem here if you can give us a debug repo.

Comment: is there any code written in viewController B viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear ?

Comment: @ trungduc @muneeba I will update the question for you guys.

Comment: @Damo it looks fine, Do you do any special thing inside `CMPThemes`?

Comment: @trungduc no it's just a colour

Comment: try to change color of backbutton and check it affect color of done button

Comment: @SumitDhariwal I just did your test, it doesn't affect the "Done" button

Comment: i think you need to set navigation bar appearance tint color,it will definatly solve you problem.

Comment: @SumitDhariwal the navigation bar already has a tint (that grey)

Comment: i think that's way your done button getting grey

Comment: set navigation bar appearance tint color blue

Comment: then check it again

Comment: No, the Done button is not on View Controller B. I did change the tint colour out of simple perversity but the Done button still changes from a bold weight to a normal weight.

Comment: write navigation appearance tint color in viewwillappear method ,where done button is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The applied tint colour is not the issue. I think, Initially when it was loading the done button from the storyboard, the doneButton Style was equals **.done** and later when you are popping to ViewControllerA, somehow the style getting changed to **.plan**, so I think setting the style below the tint should fix the issue.

**Try updating the viewWillAppear method in ViewControllerA with following code:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    doneButton.tintColor = [CMPThemes navigationBarItemColour]; // it's a blue
    doneButton.style = .done
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yup - this indeed cured the ills. well done & ty Bhavin!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue.

I have back button custom Image and when I push view controller and press back it will getting bold (Default image)

So what I did in storyboard is apply single BLANK space to **Back Button**

Step 1

-->   Tap on Navigation item

[image]

Step 2

--> Put blank space on back Button

[image]

Now you can observe that

Navigation item has one blank item

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it made no difference to how my Done button behaves

Comment: @Damo Looks like you change to font because both fonts are different    Could you share your demo project ?

Comment: I can't sorry, I have to sanitise this post to obfuscate the client - The Done button is a standard UIBarButtonItem with only a tint change (not a font change to my knowledge)

Comment: @Damo No problem I understand your concern , Now the only option left is global search navigation item in your project and check all extensions check all subclasses may be you found something from there